# How to remove default padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

In the below code I'm tried to create a dynamic menu (here it's written as static). when you click any where on the menu it will alert.

```js
document.getElementById("rightMenu").addEventListener("click",function(){
  alert("oh you clicked on right Menu");
});
```

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  }
#prof-name {
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding-right: 0 ! important;
}
```

```html
<ul id="rightMenu" class="user-profile">
   <li class="topmenu rtopmenu-display-event" id="prof-name">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class=" ico fa fa-user"></span><span id="user-name">Hello afsal khan</span><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></a>
       <ul class="profile-menu" id="profile-menu">
    <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/profile"><span class="ico fa fa-user"></span><span>Profile</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/password/change"><span class="ico fa fa-key" style ="margin-right:7px;"></span>Change Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/logout"><span class="ico fa fa-sign-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
                      </ul>
```

but the problem I'm facing is that it is alerting event if you are clicked on right side of the menu.

I have tried `padding-right: 0 ! important;` ,but which is not working
, it's not possible to set a specific width to menu because it's generating dynamically.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Well, a man does not set the width and padding of the menu (ul).. merely of a sub entry of it (li).

Comment: Maybe you should target just the <a> elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UL element is a block-level element, so if you inspect it you can see that it's 100% wide.

Either set it to display: inline-block; or give it some specific width.

```
#rightMenu { display: inline-block }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/phpaz420/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse, it will because **you have applied the click event on the entire `<ul>` element(the container of the menu) instead of just the menus** - Just target the `<a>`

Change your javascript code to

```
document.querySelector("#rightMenu a").addEventListener("click",function(){
  alert("oh you clicked on right Menu");
});
```

```js
document.querySelector("#rightMenu a").addEventListener("click",function(){
  alert("oh you clicked on right Menu");
});
```

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  }
#prof-name {
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding-right: 0 ! important;
}
```

```html
<ul id="rightMenu" class="user-profile">
   <li class="topmenu rtopmenu-display-event" id="prof-name">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class=" ico fa fa-user"></span><span id="user-name">Hello afsal khan</span><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></a>
       <ul class="profile-menu" id="profile-menu">
    <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/profile"><span class="ico fa fa-user"></span><span>Profile</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/password/change"><span class="ico fa fa-key" style ="margin-right:7px;"></span>Change Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/logout"><span class="ico fa fa-sign-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
                      </ul>
```

Comment: i appreciate your effort(+1),but I need to alert when you click any part of the menu (including li), that is why I'm tarjet the <ul>

Answer (score 0):

use this code or simply give `padding-left:0px` in `ul`

```
.user-profile
{
padding-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: i think you are jocking, can you add the snippet

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById("rightMenu").addEventListener("click",function(){
            alert("oh you clicked on right Menu");
        });
```

```css
  html,body{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    ul,li{
        list-style:none;
        padding:0;
        display:inline-block;
  
    }
    #prof-name {
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="rightMenu" class="user-profile">
    <li class="topmenu rtopmenu-display-event" id="prof-name">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class=" ico fa fa-user"></span><span id="user-name">Hello afsal khan</span><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="profile-menu" id="profile-menu">
            <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/profile"><span class="ico fa fa-user"></span><span>Profile</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/password/change"><span class="ico fa fa-key" style ="margin-right:7px;"></span>Change Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://qmsadm.local/logout"><span class="ico fa fa-sign-out"></span>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```